# Trouble with writing file

Tags: python

Write a function named "file_increment" that takes no parameters and doesn't return a value. This function will read the contents of a file named "orange.txt" which has only 1 line and it contains a well-formed integer. Read this integer and write its value plus 1 to a file named "sleeve.txt". If "sleeve.txt" already exists it must be overwritten.

```
def file_increment():
    with open("orange.txt", 'r') as rf:
        with open('sleeve.txt', 'w') as wf:
            for line in rf:
                wf.write(line+1)
```

I am getting error: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Welcome to SO btw! Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If it can't do it implicitly, make it happen explicitly:

```
wf.write(str(int(line)+1))
```

Comment: I am still getting write() argument must be str, not int.

Comment: Sorry, see my edit. You have to make it an `int` to do math, then back to a `str` to write it

Answer (score 0):

You missed the type conversion, this will work for you

```
   def file_increment():
    with open("orange.txt", 'r') as rf:
        with open('sleeve.txt', 'w') as wf:
            for line in rf:
                wf.write('{}\n'.format(str(int(line)+1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open both files the `with` context manager which is more readable. From there compute your new line and write it to the new file in string format.

```
def file_increment():
    with open("orange.txt", 'r') as rf ,open('sleeve.txt', 'w') as wf:
            line = rf.read()
            new_line = int(line) + 1
            wf.write('{}'.format(new_line))
```